# Can an Observer be added to GitHub pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Is there a way I can add somebody as an observer to my GitHub PR. I don't wan 't person A to approve my changes, but still want A to be able to see all the code changes and exchanges between the assignee and reviewer. Also get an email notification so that the observer dose not have to subscribe to anything.